# Selective focus on data table via lookup "list"

Tags: r, json, web-scraping, rvest

i want to extract specific rankings/numbers of only some districts ( i have a list of districts "01000" etc.) out of the json data (data <- jsonlite::read_json('...zdf.de/assets/data/senioren/districts.json')$districts).
I am struggling with the syntax. Can anyone help?

```
staedte_id= list("02000", "09162", "05315", "06412", "08111", "05111", "14713", 
         "05913", "05113", "04011", "14612", "03241", "09564", "05112", "05911", "05124",
         "05711", "05314", "05515", "08212", "08222", "09761", "06414", "05116")
x= data.frame()

for (i in staedte_id){
  
  data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/assets/data/senioren/districts.json')$districts$i
  
  df <- map_df(data, function(x) {
    data.frame(
      name = x %>% {.$name},
      verkehrssicherheit = x %>% {.$parts$si$indicators$si1}
    ) }
    )
  x = rbind(x,df)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the ids as a column and then filter the dataframe on the target list

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/assets/data/senioren/districts.json')$districts

df <- map_df(data, function(x) {
  data.frame(
    name = x %>% {.$name},
    rank = x %>% {.$overall$rank}
  )
})

df$id <- names(data)

staedte_id <- list("02000", "09162", "05315", "06412", "08111", "05111", "14713", 
                 "05913", "05113", "04011", "14612", "03241", "09564", "05112", "05911", "05124",
                 "05711", "05314", "05515", "08212", "08222", "09761", "06414", "05116")


df <- df[which((df$id %in% staedte_id)==TRUE), ]
df <- df[order(df$rank),]
```

---

You could also borrow functions from dplyr:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/assets/data/senioren/districts.json')$districts

df <- map_df(data, function(x) {
  data.frame(
    name = x %>% {.$name},
    rank = x %>% {.$overall$rank}
  )
})

df$id <- names(data)

staedte_id <- list("02000", "09162", "05315", "06412", "08111", "05111", "14713", 
                 "05913", "05113", "04011", "14612", "03241", "09564", "05112", "05911", "05124",
                 "05711", "05314", "05515", "08212", "08222", "09761", "06414", "05116")

df <- dplyr::arrange(dplyr::filter(df, id %in% staedte_id), rank)
```